# Is there a way to store cross-website cookies?

Tags: cookies

I have a web app that can be used on a variety of client web sites, in other words, the same user would use the app at 2 different URLs:

https://client-1.mycompany.com/webapp/index.html

https://client-2.mycompany.com/webapp/index.html

I would like to have a cookie that is **shared** by these 2 instances of a web app.

Is that possible to do? Cookies usually key in on the full web site URL.

What I'm trying to achieve is to basically key in on the path alone ("/webapp/index.html") ignoring the hostname.

Is that possible?

Please note that I'm well aware that I can achieve this by having a database accessed by both webservers in question. I'm trying to see how to do it on the client side.

If there's a solution that's not browser-independent, I **only** need it to be able to work on IE 7+.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a P3P header on each site and when a user log in to one site you will have to create for each other site an iframe (on the login successfull page) and call in it a cookie register site on each domain.